# Regular expression for updating version number

Tags: c#, regex

I have a version numbers as given below.

```
020. 000. 1234. 43567 (please note the whitespace after the dot(.))
020,000,1234,43567
20.0.1234.43567
20,0,1234,43567
```

I want a regular expression for updating the numbers after last two dots(.) to for example 1298 and 45678  (any number)

```
020. 000. 1298. 43568 (please note the whitespace after the dot(.))
020,000,1298,45678
20.0.1298.45678
20,0,1298,45678
```

Thanks,

Comment: How variable are those numbers?

Comment: This is a very, very easy expression to write. What have you tried?

Comment: (\d)+\.(\d)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)

Answer (score 3):

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, 
    @"(\d+)    # any number
    ([.,]\s*)  # dot or comma, optional whitespace
    (\d+)      # etc.
    ([.,]\s*)
    \d+
    ([.,]\s*)
    \d+", 
    "$1$2$3${4}1298${5}43568", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Note the `${4}` instead of `$4` because otherwise the following `1` would be interpreted as belonging to the group number (`$41`).

Also note the difference between `(\d+)` and `(\d)+`. While both match `1234`, the first one will capture `1234` into the group created by the parentheses. The second one will capture only `4` because the previous captures will be overwritten by the next.

Answer (score 0):

To replace version with 1298 and 43568

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=^(?:\d+[.,]\s*){2})\d+(?<seperator>[.,]\s*)\d+$");
regex.Replace(source, "1298${seperator}43568");
```

This is because

- `(?<=)` doesn't includethe group in the match but requires it to exist before the match
- `^` match start of string followed by at least one digit
- `(?:\d+[.,]\s*)` non capturing group, match at least one digit followed by a `.` or `,` followed by 0 or more spaces
- `{2}` previous match should occur twice
- `\d+` first part of the capture, 1 or more digits
- `(?<seperator>[.,]\s*)` get the seperator of a `.` or `,` followed by optional spaces into a named capture group called `seperator`
- `\d+` capture one or more digits
- `$` match end of string

in the replacement string you are just providing the replacement version and using `${seperator}` to insert the original seperator.

If you are not bothered about preserving the seperator you can just do

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=^(?:\d+[.,]\s*){2})\d+[.,]\s*\d+$");
regex.Replace(source, "1298.43568");
```